# Defining a color to be the same color of comments

Tags: colorscheme, highlight, comments

I'm using the indentLine plugin to display line indents with a continuos vertical line, and I'd like to set the color of that line to the same color of my comments.

To get the foreground color of my comments I listed all the color groups with `:hi`, checked what my colorscheme had set for the `guifg` of the `Comments` group, and set it accordingly, i.e. I have this in my `init.vim` config

```
let g:indentLine_color_gui='#5c6370'
```

which works, but if I want to change colorscheme I'd have to do this again. Is there a variable that holds the color of the comments defined by my colorscheme? What I'd like to do is

```
let g:indentLine_color_gui=<comment_guifg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `:h g:indentLine_defaultGroup` specially for this case. So it becomes simply

```
let g:indentLine_defaultGroup = 'Comment'
```

In principle, when you need to read in the color from an existing highlight group it's done like that:

```
let color = synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID('Comment')), 'fg')
```

`hlID()` returns numerical ID; `synIDtrans()` follows links if any; `synIDattr()` returns requested attribute.

This is given as an example in `:h hlID()` and it's basically what indentLine plugin does with `g:indentLine_defaultGroup` for you.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

```
execute('highlight Comment')->split('\n')->filter({i,v -> v =~# '^Comment'})[0]->split(' ')->filter({i,v -> v =~# 'guifg'})[0]->split('=')
```

as a way to parse the output of `:highlight`, but it doesn't take `link`s into account, so it will probably be wrong. (With `dracula` it gives `Blue`, but `Comment` is linked to `DraculaComment` which uses a completely different color.)

If the plugin exposes a highlight group, you can just do

```
augroup myPluginHighlights
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme * highlight link pluginGroup Comment
augroup END
```